# ¿Cómo enviar correo con formato HTML en mailx de bash?

Tags: bash

Estoy intentando enviar un correo desde el servidor del trabajo donde se adjunte un fichero con columnas y aunque en el servidor se ve correctamente, al enviarlo por mailx y abrirlo en `Outlook`las columnas salen sin respetar el formato. He probado tanto con `columns` como con `awk`.

Por eso, he intentado enviar el correo con formato `html` pero se ven las etiquetas tal cual en el cuerpo del correo, no se aplica nada. Según he encontrado en internet, el comando sería:

```sh
mailx -a "Content-Type: text/html;" -s "Prueba" -r hola@prueba.com pablo@prueba.com < prueba.html
```

Pero `-a` en `mailx` se interpreta como para adjuntar un fichero.

¿Hay alguna manera de enviar un correo con columnas y que las respete?

Comment: Prueba a quitar el `;` de `Content-Type: text/html;`. Funciona así?

Comment: Lo probé, @Julio, pero el problema es que el parámetro `-a` para `mailx` es para adjuntar un fichero. Sin embargo, en internet siempre lo referencian así.

Comment: Parece que hay diferentes versiones de mailx... Si sacas un `--help` o similar, no hay algún parámetro para "añadir cabecera" que puedas usar en lugar de `-a`?

Comment: En el `man` no viene referencia alguna para las cabeceras HTML. Creo que voy a tener que tirarlo por otro cliente...

Comment: Prueba con esta respuesta de SO:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465293/7500028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente, he encontrado la solución con `sendmail`, siguiendo la respuesta indicada en el hilo de SO que publicó @Julio.

Con esta sentencia, envío un correo con formato `html` y `sendmail`:

```sh
(
echo "From: direccion@origen.com"; 
echo "To: direccion@destino.com"; 
echo "Subject: Prueba"; 
echo "Content-Type: text/html"; 
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"; 
echo ""; 
cat prueba.html; 
) | sendmail -t
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
(
    echo -e "Content-Type: text/html\n"
    cat mail.html
 ) | mail -s "The Subject" -t user@gmail.com
```

O lo mismo en una línea:

```
(echo -e "Content-Type: text/html\n" && cat mail.html) | mail -s "The Subject" -t user@gmail.com
```

Fuente: Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465293/7500028) en SO, donde se comentan varias alternativas (La primera que comenta dejó de funcionar debido a cambios en mailx)

Comment: Me da error mail en el servidor, supongo que por políticas. Pero he enviado una prueba usando `sendmail` como comentan en ese hilo y funciona perfecto.

Comment: Perfecto! Podrías agregar tú mismo la respuesta con sendmail (y aceptarla) y así habrá varias alternativas y podrá servirle a más gente